# Pass $_GET value to web page loaded with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I have a page that loads messages for a messaging system.  This page loads external_content (another page) every second using AJAX.  The conversation ID is stored in the URL, so my method of transferring it for use in external_content was very basic:

```
$got = $_GET['conversation_id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $got;
```

However, there is a problem.  When multiple conversations are open at the same time on someone's account, each time one resets the other does too (the session variable is reset), so I need to prevent that from happening.

Thus, I somehow need to pass this GET variable through to another page where I could not simply use $_GET['conversation_id'], but I need to do it in a way so that the variable can be set more than once.  External_content is shown in a div, so I'm not sure about passing it along with $_POST or something.

Big n00bie.  Please help.

Comment: If I understood you right, you can pass it as a string containing all id's, like "2,5,7,8,12". and then you convert it to array when you need to use it.

Comment: @Gil OK, I will give it a try

Comment: @Gil what would you recommend as a way to know which value to look at (which is the conversation id)

Comment: I'm afraid any idea will be close to useless because I have no idea how your code is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in the script that the ajax request is sent to is looking for $_SESSION['id']?  And that's where your issue is when you have the multiple tabs open, they're all looking at the same variable.

So whenever you send that ajax request, attach the conversation_id

```
$.get( "YOURSCRIPT.php", {
    convo_id: "<?= $_GET['conversation_id']; ?>",
});
```

And then in YOURSCRIPT.php, instead of grabbing $_SESSION['id'], you can grab $_GET['convo_id']

**EDIT**

@Dr. McKay's way is the same as what I've just said here.  Sorry I missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you need to pass the conversation ID in the Ajax request? To do that, add it to a `script` element as a variable in your page head.

```
<script>
var g_conversationID = "<?php echo $_GET['conversation_id']; ?>";
</script>
```

Then pass it in your request:

```
$.get("mypage.php", {"conversation_id": g_conversationID}, function(data) {
    // Handle content
});
```

You could potentially parse it out of the URL using JavaScript, but this method is generally easier.

Comment: I gotta nitpick. `var g_conversationID = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['conversation_id']; ?>;` -- don't want any malicious JavaScript passing through.

Answer (score 0):

When your user on focus textarea on the current page, you can trigger onfocus event to make an ajax call to set Session superglobal for current conversation id.